# Correct pattern for dynamically loading components into an Angular application

Tags: angular, angular-routerlink

Angular newbie layout question. I'd like all content in **app.component.html** to be replaced with the content of the selected component when an item in my **navigationComponent** is clicked. With the way I have laid it out, the selected component content will simply be appended to the existing content of **app.component.html**. How do I go about achieving this?

Is the pattern simply to have `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in **app.component.html** and in the constructor of app.component.ts, load in component1 and component2 programmatically and push my example text to a component also so it can be loaded in?

Thanks

**index.html**

`<app-root><app-root>`

**app.component.html**

```
<navigationComponent></navigationComponent>

Some example text that should also be replaced when a navigation component is selected

<component1></component1>
<component2></component2>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**navigation.component.html**

```
...
<a routerLink="/component1">component1</a>
<a routerLink="/component2">component2</a>
<a routerLink="/component3">component3</a>
<a routerLink="/component4">component4</a>
<a routerLink="/component5">component5</a>
```